# How to change the log and startup script path in PM2 for windows

Tags: node.js, windows-server-2008, pm2

I have a node application and I am using  [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)  to run the application.By this i have achieved to run the app without the Active command prompt.

Now i am trying to run the same when windows restart, so for windows I have found PM2 will not work and it needs another module [PM2-Windows-startup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-startup) so I have used and it is working fine in my local machine.

But when I am trying the same in server machine then which have many machines in cluster, the PM2 logs has changed its default path from *C:\users\admin.pm2\logs* to *H:\logs* and the startup script also generated in the H:\ when giving this command `PM2 save` so whenever server machine restarted also the startup script is not running results the app going down.

How can i change the path for logs and startup script in PM2 for windows machine.How to give the ***PM2_Home*** env variable for PM2 and PM2-windows-startup

I have tried [PM2-windows-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service) following [image of steps](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/) in one of comments,then it shown installed and when i check `PM2 list` no app is running.

This is the image i found in commants in that page[image of steps](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/)
[image: Image from PM2 site comments]
  Show  my result image below
[image: My result image]

Comment: Shouldn't the question title be about changing the log and startup script path? Because it suggests that you are not able to do that, but the description says you were successful, just not on server machine.

Comment: @DushyantBangal Thanx, changed. Could you know the solution

Comment: not really, if it was about service, I could've been helpful, but I havent really used it as much to know about paths, etc

Comment: Have you tried this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-windows-service

Comment: @DushyantBangal No, it shown that it was  inspired by pm2-windows-startup, so i used pm2-windows-startup

Comment: try using it just to be sure its not something related to the package

Comment: OK, but client has instred in this packages so.,

Comment: `pm2-windows-service` has an environment variable `PM2_HOME`, this might be it; maybe its in `pm2-windows-startup` as well

Comment: have you tried using command prompt with admin privileges while setting it up? It might be possible on server you dont have access to `\users\admin`

Comment: @DushyantBangal. Yes I have did everything in Admin Privileges. and I am also asking the question how to give the PM2_Home env variable

Comment: Its not in the package you are using, I checked the source. But it is in the one I suggested. But you say your client insists on using the first one

Comment: I suggest you try `pm2-windows-service` once, if its working, you can insist client/seniors to use it. Nobody cares much which one you are using if everything works.

Comment: @DushyantBangal  I have tried `pm2-windows-service` after the npm install and then the `pm2-service-install [-n <service name>]` cmd it is showing for homepath and after completing it is showing installed but when i run `pm2 list` nothing is under running

Comment: @DushyantBangal I have updated the question which i got.